# While authenticating why am in getting req.profile undefined

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, express-jwt

my getUser route

```
router.get("/user/:userId", isSignedIn, isAuthenticated, getUser)
```

isSignedIn is a middleware

```
exports.isSignedIn = expressJwt({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    userProperty: "auth"
})
```

isAuthenticated is also a middleware

```
exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.profile[enter image description here][1])
    const isUserAuthenticated = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id;
    if(!isUserAuthenticated){
        return res.status(403).json({
            message: "user not authenticated"
        })
    }
    next();
}
```

Why am I getting req.profile as undefined due to which I'm getting user is not authenticated?

Comment: It should be `req.body.profile`

Comment: No. It is correct. Also I figured what was the issue. I need to get the 'userId' param and find user from DB and then set the req.profile = user in order to get it in isAuthenticated middleware. The mistake was i was using '/user' instead of 'user' which was causing this error.